# Sets in raphaeljs not real groups? Transform order

Tags: raphael

I'm having an issue with sets and how transforms are applied. I'm coming from a graphics background, so I'm familiar with scene graphs as well as the normal SVG group syntax, but Raphael is confusing me. Say I have a circle and a set, on which I want to apply a transform.

```js
circle = paper.circle(0,0.5)
set = paper.set()
```

If I add the circle first, and then transform, it works.

```js
set.push circle
set.transform("s100,100")
```

To make a 50 radius circle. If I reverse the order, however,

```js
set.transform("s100,100")
set.push circle
```

The transform is not applied.

This seems as though it will break many, many rendering and animation type algorithms, where your groups/transforms hold your articulation state, and you add or remove objects to them instead of recreating the entire transform every time. Is there an option somewhere in the documentation that I am not seeing that addresses this, or was this functionality discarded in favor of simplicity? It seems very odd to be missing, given that it is supported directly and easily in the group hierarchy of SVG itself... do I need to *manually* apply the transform from the set to any children added after the set is transformed?

Comment: Don't forget to mark some answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that check mark was clickable. d'oh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raphaël's `set`s are merely intended to provide a convenient way of managing groups of shapes as unified sets of objects, by aggregating `element` related actions and delegating them (by proxying the corresponding methods in the set level) to each shape sequentially.

> It seems very odd to be missing, given that it is supported directly
>   and easily in the group hierarchy of SVG itself...

Well, Raphaël is not an attempt to elevate the SVG specs to a JavaScript based API, but rather to offer an abstraction for vector graphics manipulation regardless of the underlying implementation (be it SVG in modern browsers, or VML in IE<9). Thus, `set`s are by no means representations of SVG groups.

> do I need to *manually* apply the transform from the set to any
>   children added after the set is transformed?

Absolutely not, you only need to make sure to add any shapes to the set before applying transformations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd be really curious to hear what technical design reason there is for sets *not* being groups, because at first glance it seems like a rather... odd... decision. It makes some ways I'm used to manipulating scene graphs work very differently. I can think of numerous examples of when you would be adding/removing/enabling/disabling children of a group *after* you know what its transform is.

Comment: well, if you're interested in Raphaël's design decisions and motivations, you could try and [contact Dmitry Baranovskiy](http://dmitry.baranovskiy.com/), the library's author. you may also (and should) **[browse the code](https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/)**. i suppose JavaScripters are accustomed to arrays so dealing with a live set of objects comes naturally, and again, `set`s do not represent groups as to serve as an abstraction layer (VML is lacking the *groups* concept).

Comment: If the primary purpose to abstract the VML/SVG switch, I guess that makes more sense. Everyone was recommending it as a general purpose interface for drawing SVG, so I didn't realize the degree to which that drove its design.

Answer (score 6):

Sets in Raphael are just simple Arrays.

When you perform some actions on set, Raphael goes through all members via `for(...){}` loop.

Raphael doesn't support SVG groups `<g></g>`

**UPDATE** Raphael's code:

```
// Set
var Set = function (items) {
    this.items = [];
    this.length = 0;
    this.type = "set";
    if (items) {
        for (var i = 0, ii = items.length; i < ii; i++) {
            if (items[i] && (items[i].constructor == elproto.constructor || items[i].constructor == Set)) {
                this[this.items.length] = this.items[this.items.length] = items[i];
                this.length++;
            }
        }
    }
},
```

As you can see, all items are stored in `this.items` which is array.

Comment: So why -1? :) I updated my answer with Raphael's code to show that it's true.

Comment: Thank you! :) BTW currently I'm working on my own Raphael extension which will support real SVG groups.

Comment: @oyatek did you ever come up with your `<g>`-in-Raphael implementation? I think it is the one feature that's really missing if you want to create more complex graphics apps with raphael!