# animating a rectangle with text in Raphael javascript library

Tags: javascript, raphael

I am quite new to javascript and to Raphael. I am trying to move a button-like rectangle with text inside. Here is my code :

```
window.onload = function() {
  var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), "100%", "100%");
  var box1 = paper.rect(100, 100, 120, 50, 10).attr({fill: 'darkorange', stroke: '#3b4449', 'stroke-width': 2, cursor: 'pointer'});

  var box2 = paper.rect(400,100,120,50,10).attr({fill: 'lightblue', stroke: '#3b4449', 'stroke-width': 2});
  var text2 = paper.text(box2.attrs.x + box2.attrs.width/2,box2.attrs.y + box2.attrs.height/2,"[x: " + box2.attrs.x + " y: " + box2.attrs.y + "]").attr({"font-family": "arial", "font-size": 16});
  var button2 = paper.set();
  button2.push(box2); 
  button2.push(text2);

  box1.click(function(){
    // this did not work
    // button2.animate({x: 100, y: 50 }, 1000, 'bounce', function() { // callback function
    //  text2.attr('text',"[x: " + box2.attrs.x + " y: " + box2.attrs.y + "]");
    // });
    button2.animate({transform: "t100,100"}, 1000, 'bounce', function() { // callback function
        text2.attr('text',"[x: " + box2.attrs.x + " y: " + box2.attrs.y + "]");
    });
  });
}
```

The `button2.animate({x: 100, y: 50 }, 1000, 'bounce');` line did not worked properly, the text was not in the right position at the end. By using the `transform:` I can not use coordinates, I would have to compute them. Also I am not able to get the right coordinates of the blue box at the end when using the `transform` method.

I was not able to find any answer yet, hope someone can help me.

Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer about your new questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't explain how exactly you want to move your button, I'm assuming you want to move the `box2` above `box1`.

There are some misunderstandings and errors in your code, allow me explain one by one.

### Why the first way cause text move to wrong position at end ?

Because a set is NOT a group of element which knows its relative position inside the group. A set is merely a collection of elements which is designed for us to operate them in a more convenient way.

So, the code below will move all element in the set to (100, 50)

```
set.animate({x: 100, y: 50 }, 1000);
```

and that's why the text is there.

I couldn't find the document, but you can find some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14003371/554279) .

### Why x, y in attributes seems to be wrong when using transform ?

No, the attribute is correct.

When you transform an element, the result of the transformation will not reflect back to the attributes. You can think like this, when `transform()`, you are actually attach "transformation" to the elements. Therefore :

```
paper.circle(100, 100, 5).transform("t100");
```

You can describe the circle as :

*a circle at (100, 100) which will be moved 100px horizontally.*

but not - *a circle at (200, 100) which will be moved 100px horizontally.*

---

So, here is the code that dose what you want, note that I'm using `getBBox()` to get coordinate of the `button2` set.

```
  box1.click(function(){
    var moveX = box1.attr("x") - button2.getBBox().x;
    var moveY = (box1.attr("y") - 50) - button2.getBBox().y;
    button2.animate({transform: "t" + moveX + "," + moveY}, 1000, 'ease-in-out', function () {
      text2.attr('text', "[x: " + button2.getBBox().x + "y: " + button2.getBBox().x + "]");
    });
  });
```

Welcome to SO, and suggest you to write a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) next time.

---

### UPDATE

> I do not fully understand why the transformation does not reflect back
>   to the attributes. If I move the circle at the position (100,100)
>   100px horizontally it will results in a circle at position (200,100).
>   This is what the bounding box gives me. So why I am not able to get
>   the coordinates from the circle after the transformation and have to
>   use the bounding-box method ?

Transform DOSE NOT change the original attribute in the element, because it is something you attach to a element, not function that change a element directly. If you want to know attributes AFTER the transformation applied, you have to use `getBBox()`, or take a look about [matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10939195/).

This is how Raphael.js works. Either you use bounding box function, or extend the Raphael.js by yourself like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046811/)

I have changed my previous answer about how I describe transformation a little bit, hope it can help you to understand better this time.

> Your code works great but it has the drawback, that you have to
>   compute the transformation values instead of simply setting the
>   position. Is there any other way to move a rectangle with text inside
>   to a position of your choice ?

You can always write helper functions to do these ugly jobs for you anyway, I don't see there's anything wrong with it.

Comment: Thank you very much. In between I read about the transformation method elsewhere and it helped me to understand how it works.

Comment: You're welcome :). If you think my answer did solve your problem, you can accept the answer by click the check near the vote number.